# regular expression to match diverse types of http-type string

Tags: javascript, regex, linux

In a text file,there is a string encoding the http-related information. The followings are the string examples

```
URL 123.34.45.7:http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html
```

or

```
URL 123.45.67.8:http://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1&_v=j41&a=1071188231&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fm.sherdog.com%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Sherdog.com%3A%20UFC%2C%20Mixed%20Martial%20Arts%20(MMA)%20News%2C%20Results%2C%20Fighting&sd=32-bit&sr=320x480&vp=320x460&je=0&_utma=236548035.1293902652.1385044241.1442
```

I wrote some regular expression to extract the part until http, such as

```
url)\\s\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d+[.]\\d+[:](http|https|ftp)
```

but I am not sure how to write regular expression to match the part following `http`. Thanks.

Comment: so you want to capture (it appears to) IP address? text before http?

Comment: I would like to capture the whole string URL 123.34.45.7:http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html  from a large text file,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following regex:

```
/^(URL[^:]+:)(?:.*?\/\/)(.*)/gm
```

Demo:

```
var re = /^(URL[^:]+:)(?:.*?\/\/)(.*)/gm; 
var str = 'URL 123.34.45.7:http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(m[1]+m[2]);
}
```

It will print:

```
URL 123.34.45.7:captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to extract the whole string infact, like URL 123.34.45.7:http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html from a whole text file

Comment: Well, that's easy. It's already capturing including URL but I wasn't sure what you need to displayed just IP portion

Answer (score 0):

For finding a string of the type "URL [IP ADDRESS]:[URL]" within a given (possibly large) string, try this:

```
var patterns = {
   ip: '\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}',
   url: (() => {
      var protocol = '(http(s)?(:\/\/))?(www\.)?';
      var domains = '[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+';
      var params = '([-a-zA-Z0-9:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)';
      return protocol + domains + params;
   })()
}

var regex = new RegExp(`URL ${patterns.ip}:${patterns.url}`);
```

check out this fiddle: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/syk6scwo/)

Answer (score 0):

`.*` will match any character any number of times.

So if you add that to the end of the string you'll get:

```
url\s\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+[:](http|https|ftp).*
```

That will match until the end of the line.

Note that I've unescaped `\\` to just `\` for readability. You may need to re-escape them.

[Here's an example of that regular expression at work](https://regex101.com/r/oX6sZ3)